# The title font change my body font

Tags: fonts, miktex

I'm writing a PS and like some professional papers, the title font is different from that of content. I'm trying to mimic that and got a template from internet and did some modifications. However, after using that, I noticed that my body font is not the same as default any more. It's blurry and thinner. I studied for a long time and couldn't find a way to solve the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath} % for \Box, \mathbb, split, etc.
% \usepackage[]{showkeys} % shows label names
\usepackage{cite} % sorts citation numbers appropriately
\usepackage{path}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
%\usepackage{showframe}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe
\usepackage{eso-pic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=3in]{logo.jpg}}}%
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose}
\author{\textbf{Xxx Xx}}
\date{\textbf{Ph.D. Applicant}}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle% prints the title block

\vspace{\baselineskip}


I have loved mathematics ever since I was a child.
\end{document}
```

I found that if I comment out

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

then the font of the title is the default font of Latex and it's first letter won't be bigger as I expected. That means

```
\textsc{\@title}
```

is not working....However, in this case, all the font, the title and body, is back to normal.

So, how could I make my body font back to default after I use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: For T1 encoding, you should add `\usepackage{lmodern}` to use the Latin Modern fonts. With the default Computer Modern, you'll get bitmap fonts, hence their blurry aspect.

Comment: @Bernard Or install `cm-super`.

Comment: '\usepackage{lmodern}' will also change my title font....that's not what I want